# selenium IDE 101 - how to visit any page

Tags: development

I've used the SeleniumIDE extensively on Linux (Ubuntu) a while ago, now I'm trying to get it working on a Mac (OSX v10.9) in the Firefox browser.
I have it installed but it doesn't seem to be interacting with the browser.  When I try and record scripts, nothing happens.  If I manually add a test case for open('http://www.google.com') I get

```
[info] Executing: |open('http://www.google.com') | | |
[error] Unknown command: 'open('http://www.google.com')'
```

See this screenshot for more background:

[image]

Comment: Are you using some combination of the supported browsers / OS / IDE listed here? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp Adding a little more detail that documents your precise setup might go a long way to getting a quality answer instead of guesswork.

Comment: Added more info, the browser, the OS version and a screenshot showing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that you put the Base URL up top, e.g. http://www.google.com and then you put the rest of the url, e.g. /images in the 'Target' field.

If you only want to go to the base page of the site (e.g. "http://www.google.com") you just use that for the BaseURL and then use in the 'Command' line use 'open' with no parameters) but keep the Target field blank.